# Cannot Add new Google Account on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, gmail, google

I have existing Gmail accounts for Mail on my iPhone, but I want to add a new one. I went to Settings -> Passwords & Accounts -> Add Account and I tap Google, and nothing happens. Here is a GIF:

[image]

This is iOS 12.1 on iPhone 6. Any ideas of how get around this to add a new Gmail account? Rebooting the phone, toggling WiFi off/on, and holding the lock + home button for 15 seconds to reset the phone did not fix either.

Comment: It's highly likely that it's a bug in iOS 12. Lot of users have reported this issue and it is all over the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I held my finger on the Google button for about 15 seconds, let go, went back 1 screen, then tapping the Google button worked. I don't like this answer because I'm not anywhere near certain if doing this fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED IT!!
Reset your Network settings. 
Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings 
Cheers.

Comment: Doing this did not fix the problem for me. Also, doing this deleted all of my WiFi passwords.

Comment: it did not work me too. mine's iOS 12.3.1